# No Pipe found with name '...' - Angular(2+)

Tags: javascript, angular, pipe

I made a custom pipe and want to use it in my project, but getting this error while implementing that pipe : "src/app/portfolio/port-main/port-main.component.html:11:124 - error NG8004: No pipe found with name 'filter'."

My filter.pipe.ts code:

```
   import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

   @Pipe({
     name: 'filter'
   })
```

Here is the code snippet where i wanna use this pipe:
*Want to mention that this component is inside a routing module which has lazy loading implemented. That's why I didn't import this component into app.module.ts file.*

```
 <div class="card mb-3 me-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12" *ngFor="let img of PortfolioArray | filter:ValueText:'category'">
...
</div>
```

Here is my app.module.ts file where I import the custom pipe:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './home/home.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { SidebarComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar.component';
import { SidebarDownComponent } from './sidebar/sidebar-down/sidebar-down.component';
import { FilterPipe } from './pipes/filter.pipe';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    NotFoundComponent,
    SidebarComponent,
    SidebarDownComponent,
    FilterPipe
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

If anyone knows how to resolve this issue please let me know. Willing to share more code if needed.

*Edited*
Here is the module where I'm using the pipe:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { PortfolioRoutingModule } from './portfolio-routing.module';
import { PortMainComponent } from './port-main/port-main.component';
import { FilterPipe } from '../pipes/filter.pipe';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    PortMainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    PortfolioRoutingModule
  ],
  exports: [FilterPipe]
})
export class PortfolioModule { }
```

Comment: I assume you've just posted only the pipe's decorator, right? Are you using the pipe in a component from the same module?

Comment: no, that pipe not in the same module. I added the code of the module where I'm using the pipe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your posted code, you could fix your issue by adding the `FilterPipe` to the `declarations` array in your `PortfolioModule` and removing it in `AppModule`.

The issue you're currently facing is that you want to use a pipe/component/directive in a module where they're not declared. As soon as you want to use one of those in multiple modules you need to create another module with which you can share these, let's call it `SharedModule`.

A shared module in your case looks like this:

```
// An helper array to reduce code
const ELEMS = [FilterPipe];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [ELEMS],
    imports: [CommonModule],
    exports: [ELEMS]
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

The `exports` array is important because you can only use components/pipes/directives which are in that array in other modules.